How can I merge multiple git commits with conflicts on submodule?
I have a repo with submodules. In this repo, I have multiple commits with the same parent P, that all update the submodule to a different commit (let's call them A, B and C). If I try to merge two of them, e.g.
git checkout P
git merge A B

I get a conflict on the submodule that I can fix before continuing the merge, as I expect:
Fast-forwarding to: A
Trying simple merge with B
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
ERROR: my_submodule: Not merging conflicting submodule changes.
fatal: merge program failed
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

However, if I try to merge more than two commits, e.g.
git checkout P
git merge A B C

then the merge fails completely without a way to fix it:
Fast-forwarding to: A
Trying simple merge with B
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
ERROR: my_submodule: Not merging conflicting submodule changes.
fatal: merge program failed
Automated merge did not work.
Should not be doing an octopus.
Merge with strategy octopus failed.

Can you explain why there is such a difference? And what are my options to achieve a merge commit with A, B and C as parents?

I found a solution to my problem here: using git commit-tree to create a commit with custom parents and custom content. The original question was not exactly the same as this one, but I'm voting to close as duplicate anyway since I don't think we can get better answers than the one linked.

Git's handling of submodule merges, especially when it comes to conflicting submodule updates, is the cause of the behavior you're seeing.
1- Merging Two Commits:
Git tries a three-way merge with the two commits (A and B) and the common ancestor (P) when you merge them. Git can give you a method to manually settle any conflicts that may arise in the submodule updates. You can still resolve the dispute even though you see the error because of this.
2- Merging Several Commits:
Git tries to do a "octopus" merge, which is designed for merging several branches, when you attempt to merge more than two commits (such as A, B, and C). However, compared to standard two-way merges, octopus merges have more stringent requirements and manage conflicts differently. Git fails entirely without offering a chance to resolve conflicts because it is unable to do so automatically, particularly when it comes to submodules.

That's what I don't understand: in both cases, git fails to automatically handle the conflict; why is it offering me a chance to fix them in the first case and not in the second?

Actually maybe I would have the same problem if my 3 commits were modifying the same line in a source file. Is it just a matter of git not being able to present a conflict with more than two sides?

Because it can easily identify changes and potential resolutions, Git is better at showing conflicts when there are only both sides involved. Instead of attempting to provide a conflicting state, Git fails the merging when there are several conflicting branches because of the difficulty in resolving such modifications. The constraints of the octopus merge approach and the fundamental complexity of merges are reflected in this behavior. Parallel branch merges or more regulated submodule update management are frequently easier ways to prevent such problems.
